# <UL> <LI> tag issue in firefox

Tags: html, tags, listings

When I am aligning items vertically using `<ul>` & `<li>` tag, the following issue occurs

My code is as follows :

```
< ul>
< li>
yahoo
< /li>
< li>
google
< /li>
< ul>
```

I'm getting yahoo google listed horizontally in Firefox...but in IE am able to get it vertically.

Plz help :)

Comment: I have no idea what you want... Do want the list to be vertical or horizontal? I can't understand your problem

Comment: Do you have any CSS? Layout/positioning is per definition controlled by (browser-default) CSS styles, not by HTML. Besides, your HTML is far from valid. `< ul>` doesn't render a list, `<ul>` do.

Answer (score 8):

You did not properly close your `ul` tag. You're missing a `/`. It should be:

```
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<ul> <!-- Begins an unordered-list -->
  <li>Yahoo</li>
  <li>Google</li>
</ul> <!-- Ends an unordered-list -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not stick spaces before the tagname. For example, it should be `<ul>`, not `< ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not correct - ul tag is not closed.

Once you've fixed that both browsers will show what you wanted.

Comment: Didn't knew SO was a race. That's a very lame excuse when talking about unnoticeable gaps of less than a few minutes.